# jQuery Cycle Plugin Breaks in IE6 with background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-6

I'm using the jQuery Cycle plugin along with the tutorial here: Net Tuts tutorial "building-an-auto-scrolling-slideshow-that-works-with-and-without-javascript"

It all works good if I give my containing `<div>` a background *color*, but as soon as I apply a background via `url()`, my slide navigation which was originally positioned absolutely to the top right gets bumped down below my slides in IE6.

It doesn't matter if I apply the background to the `<div>` it's currently on, or the one the slideshow actually uses, or the `<ul>` that contains the slides.

You can witness the problem here: http://ainsworthstudios.com/beeson/example/ looks fine in IE7 and FF, but the nav is bumped down below the slides in IE6.

I think it has something to do with the clear type fix in Cycle, but I'm not certain. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You have my sympathies - IE6 is a pain in the ass that should have been put out of our misery long ago.  Is IE6 in Quirks Mode or Standards Mode?

Comment: I'm not super savvy on quirks mode, but I think it's in Standards mode with this DTD: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

Answer (score 0):

Ended up hacking it up a bit by making an additional `<div>` positioned directly above the old `<div>` in the HTML, giving that a background, and positioning both of them on top of each other to simulate the background I was hoping for originally. It's working in IE6, IE7, and FF, so hopefully that's a good enough "solution."